# Проблема в парсинге

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium

Пишу парсер для PROZORRO, использую `Python`. Написал скрипт, чтобы работало нажатие на кнопку. Кнопка нажимается, и, раз она нажата, то скрипт должен вывести 20 ссылок, но он выводит только 10:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def main():
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get('https://prozorro.gov.ua/tender/search?query=освіта')
    btn = driver.find_element_by_class_name('show-more')

    btn.click()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='items-list']//a")
for i in links:
    print(i.get_attribute('href'))

driver.quit()
```

Что я делаю не так ?

Answer (score 1):

Зашёл на данный сайт, сделал просмотр кода данной страницы, далее в ctrl+F вбил:
`class="items-list"` выдало 10 совпадений. Проблема в следующей строке:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='items-list']//a")
```

а именно: `[@class='items-list']` - он находит классы только с идентичным названием.

Comment: А что тогда мне надо туда подставить ?

Comment: А зависит от того что тебе нужно, именно чтобы 20 
20 ссылок? Тогда нужно дописать кликер после цикла, чтобы он нажимал на кнопку с классом show-more и запускал заново цикл для новых ссылок.

Comment: Ну вообще, нужно собрать все ссылки на этой странице.

Comment: Как я понял надо использовать рекурсию ? Просматриваем все ссылки --> записываем их в список --> нажимаем кнопку ---> и всё заново ?

Answer (score 0):

Я решил данную проблему.

````
```python
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import csv
import time
links_list = []


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://prozorro.gov.ua/tender/search?query=освіта')


def new_links():
    links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='items-list']//a")
    for i in links:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i.get_attribute('href'))
        b = i.get_attribute('href')
        a = ({
            'link':b
        })
        links_list.append(a)
        print(len(links_list))

    new_start()

def new_start():
    btn = driver.find_element_by_class_name('show-more')
    btn.click()
    new_links()
new_start()
driver.quit()

```
````

До меня дошло что у сервера не хватает времени на обработку запроса при нажатии на кнопку. Поэтому было решено добавить остановку времени в 1 сек. Тут всё ещё наверное много лишнего. Если кто-то считает моё решение не правильным, то пожалуйста напишите что не так.